# The ex unit is not proportional on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I have noticed this strange issue on iOS.

On jsFiddle, 1ex equals 7px. You would assume that 10ex would be 70px. But it is actually 71px!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq8ww/)

The output on iOS7 iPad:

```
7  // 1ex in px
14
21
28
35
42
50
57
64
71  // 10ex in px
```

On Chrome and IE11, I confirmed that they are proportional.

I used `getBoundingClientRect()` so these values shouldn't be rounded. But the only reason I can think of is that they are indeed rounded values. Is this a bug?

I hope it is not "just because that's how the browser works". Because of this inconsistency, I'm having trouble calculating width of some components.

Comment: It rounds off to the nearest pixel. The actual value is probably something like 7.08 pixels.

Comment: http://destination-code.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/font-size-relative-length-units-ex.html here, it's different in every browser by the looks of it and also varies with font-family. (granted the browsers specified in the table are old, however i'm fairly sure it's viable to assume such issues are still around with modern browsers)

Comment: @MrLister It shouldn't round off because I used `getBoundingClientRect` to get the pixel value of it.

Comment: @AndrewMatthew I'm aware that ex value is dependent on font-family, font-size, font-weight, and browser. My question is why it is not proportional on iOS.